# only ie / Right margin formed inside html

Tags: html, css

```css
*{  margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


a{ text-decoration: none}
ul, li, il{ list-style: none}
img{ vertical-align: top}

html,
body,
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Only "ie" creates the right margin of the screen.

This is how the screen looks like this.

[image]

How do I solve this?
i'm not using max-width

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please DO NOT paste screenshots of code. If people want to help you out, this forces them to have to type it out on themselves. By inclucing the code, it makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You should change your snipped, it's not same with screenshot that you shared

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help to ask questions.